# Can a Power Mac 8500/180 use a LCD monitor?

Tags: mac, lcd

A friend has a Power Macintosh 8500/180 (yes a bit of a classic from the mid-90s!) and wishes to upgrade the monitor from the huge CRT it is now using to LCD.

Looking at the specs of this machine it has a DB15 display port, which it seems can output via VGA via an adapter such as [this](http://www.lindy.co.uk/shop/showProductDetail.do?orderNumber=70187&source=search).  Any idea if this would work?

I seem to remember that in years gone by Mac's were only compatible with Multisync monitors. Is this the case with LCD? 
In other words, would any old LCD work, or should a multisync LCD be purchased?

Likewise, would a driver be required, and would it matter if the monitor was widesceen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this advice my friend bought a second hand multisync monitor from an auction site with a native resolution that matched the output of the graphics mode he was working in. The adapter successfully enabled the connection to the DB15 port. Thankfully no drivers were required. 
Unfortunately I'm not in a position to check the quality of picture, or more details of setup since I am not located nearby.

Answer (score 2):

I used that kind of adapter for the LCD on an old Macintosh as well. It worked well.
Let me just verify the modell name and update this post.